# store string into array

Tags: mysql, laravel

In MySQL, I have a field name postcodes and the type is LONGTEXT. It stores several postcodes being separated by comma. How would I retrieve that and store it as an array for other use ?

Answer (score 0):

Store it as a JSON field in MySQL, Laravel encode and decode them when you retrieve and save them respectively

in your migration

`$table->json('field_name');`

then in the model

`protected $json = ['field_name'];`

then whenever you access the field, laravel will convert it to an array for you, you don't have to call any explicit methods.

**Doc** - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 0):

you can use the PHP method `explode()`.

one think you can't do, is to do a `where x = x` on it in the database.

In the model, you can set the mutator methods:

```
public function getPostcodesAttribute($value) {
    return explode(',',$value);
}

public function setPostcodesAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['postcodes'] = implode(',',$value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you have the result stored in a string like this:

```
$s = "6000,5447"; //$s = $array->postcodes;
```

you can get the each value on an index in an array using this:

```
$values= explode(",", $s);
echo $values[0]; // 6000
```

Or even better.. you can store it as json, and retrieve it as json in array format.

Answer (score 0):

```
// the final array all the post codes are collected.
$postCodes = [];

foreach (Model::pluck('postcodes') as $stringCodes)
    foreach (explode(',', $stringCodes) as $postCode) $postCodes[] = $postCode;
```